# jQuery Autocomplete to populate multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have three textboxes:

- phoneNumber
- contactName
- ContactAge

And I am using jQuery Autocomplete to the first textbox- phoneNumber.
I am getting phone Numbers from DB using GenericHandler.

What I want to do is, after selecting the phone number using Autocomplete, populate the other two fields using phoneNumber(since its the primary key).

This is ContactHandler.ashx:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string term = context.Request["term"] ?? "";
        List<string> listContactNumbers = new List<string>();

        string myConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ArtistManagementSystemConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnection))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spGetContactNumbers", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter()
            {
                ParameterName = "@term",
                Value = term
            });
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                listContactNumbers.Add(dr["Cell"].ToString());
            }
        }

        JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(listContactNumbers));
    }
```

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#phoneNumber').autocomplete({
            source: 'ContactHandler.ashx'
        });
    });

</script>
```

I am lost at this point. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is a very common feature. Google for "jquery autocomplete cascading"

Comment: You basically need to make an ajax call to the server and get the details based on the unique phone number. See the duplicate.